# Import Sikuli in Jython project

Tags: python, jython, importerror, sikuli

I am trying to include sikuli in a python based project.
I know to run sikuli I should have a jython interprater.SO I installed jython 2.5.3 and executed my file with the following command

```
jython test.py
```

Content of test.py is

```
sys.path.append("path\to\sikuli-java.jar")
from org.sikuli.basics import Debug
```

Error:

```
from org.sikuli.basics import Debug
ImportError: No module named org.sikuli.basics
```

Could any one suggest How can import sikuli in my python project if I want to run it with jython interprater?

Any clues are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using to to write/run the code?

The following must be true:

- Jython must be installed
- Jython must be the interpreter used
- The IDE must support Sikuli
- Sikuli must be configured in the IDE to run without launching through a .jar

The simplest option is to use the Sikuli-IDE, however as the project grows this could become a liability.
I recommend configuring Eclipse like outlined here: http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/040-other-ide.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IDE like PyCharm and set up your jython interpreter there. I've mentioned some steps related to this on [SikuliX Bat file not running in Py Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080589/sikulix-bat-file-not-running-in-py-script/46423871#46423871)