# SikuliX Bat file not running in Py Script

Tags: python, sikuli

I have a .Bat file that executes a sikuliX command that refuses to launch from inside my Py Code. (All my other .Bat files work without issues)

This is the code it is in:

```
os.system("start cmd /k C:\\Blah\\Bla\\Documents\\Folder\\SikuliXTest.bat")
```

My other Bat files use this same structure and no problems but this guy refuses to launch yet works fine when running independently. It appears it is launching it in some form due to the error output below:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Blah\Folder\Folder\GalaxyNote3.sikuli\GalaxyNote3.py", line
>   14, in 
>       click(Pattern("1495231593542.png").similar(0.90)) NameError: name 'click' is not defined

But why is it not executing the same as if I run the Bat directly? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the `SikuliXTest.bat` file, or the python script that executes the .bat file import the sikuli module? similar to what is described here https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/146640

Comment: I have this added at the top imports as stated in that doc from sikuli import*

Comment: Does this need to share similar directories/install paths?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import sikuli library in your python code. Also, jython interpreter needs to be set up giving your sikuli jar path

1) To import sikuli library

`from sikuli import *`

2) To setup jython interpreter and sikuli, you'll need to use these settings in your pycharm editor settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it more please, How
Can i import sikuli library in python code?
Jython interpreter setup ?

Comment: 1) To import sikuli library
`from sikuli import *`
2) IDEs like pycharm need jython interpreter set up. Which IDE are you using to run your code?

Comment: i am using pyCharm, Please help me on it
So i can use Sikuli functionality in my .py python code file OR
Can i use python libraries like pandas,  matplotlib etc. in my Sikuli script?

Comment: Try the settings I've just mentioned above

Comment: Okay, i have done with jython interpreter setup.
Now when i write ```from sikuli import *``` in my hello.py file its saying:
```ImportError: No module named sikuli```
Can i do something like we can do it in JAVA just import the Sikuli library, and play with Screen object to do sikuli features in my JAVA code?

Comment: I want to do the same thing as Screen object in Java but in my own python file

Comment: I have found that both of the following statements are needed.                                import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython
from sikuli import *